# Passing parameters back and forth between Powershell and Access VBA

Tags: powershell, ms-access, vba

I am using VBA to kick off a PowerShell script. I am able to pass some parameters from the VBA application to the PowerShell script, however I am unable to figure out how to get powershell to feed data back to the VBA application.

I appreciate any insight you guys might have for me in figuring this out.

Thank you.

Comment: You could make the PowerShell script update a table in Access and read the data from there after the script finishes.

Comment: About the only other thing I can imagine working is writing to text files from PowerShell and then using a Timer to look for those text files and read them.

Comment: Ansgar - How would I get the PowerShell script to update the Access table? If I can get that to work I think i can come up with a solution for what I am looking to accomplish!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to insert something into the Access database like this:

```
$db = 'C:\path\to\your.mdb'

$value = "..."

$conn = New-Object -COM ADODB.Connection
$conn.open("Provider = Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$db")

$cmd = New-Object -COM ADODB.Command
$cmd.ActiveConnection = $conn
$cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [table] ([field]) VALUES ('$value')"
$cmd.Execute()

$conn.Close()
```